# How to extract multiple zips into one folder without creating separate folders with zip name? Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Here's my script in powershell

```
$today   = (Get-Date).ToString('dd_MM_yyyy')
$LocalPath = "C:\Builds\$today"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $LocalPath
$RemotePath = "C:\Builds\zip\$today"
$Max_hours = "-5"
#Max_mins = "-5"
$Curr_date = get-date

#Checking date and then copying file from LocalPath to RemotePath
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $RemotePath))
{
    if($file.LastWriteTime -gt ($Curr_date).addhours($Max_hours))
    {

        Get-ChildItem "C:\Builds\zip\$today\*pc*.*" | % {& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "x" "-aoa" $_.fullname "-oC:\Builds\$today"}
    }
    ELSE
    {"not extracting $file"
    }

}
```

I've got a few *.zip files which I want to extract into a specific folder. The problem is, that 7zip creates subfolders with *.zip name and extract files into this folders.

Eg. I've got **a.zip**, **b.zip** and **c.zip** files and I want them to be extracted exactly in Builds folder. Right now after my command they are extracted to:

Builds/a/(here a.zip files)

Builds/b/(here b.zip files)

Builds/c/(here c.zip files)

I want them all to be in Builds/(here a,b,c files) with full directory paths.
Are there any 7zip options in shell to do that?

'-e' option exctracts all files without folders paths and thats now what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PowerShell v5 you can use [Expand-Archive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive) instead of 7zip:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Builds\zip\$today\*pc*.*" | % {Expand-Archive $_ -DestinationPath "C:\Builds\$today"}
```

---

**EDIT:**

I do not get folders created when using the command.

Zip file containing a file:

[image: zip file]

Running `Expand-Archive C:\aaaa\nuget350.zip -DestinationPath C:\bbbb`

What is extracted:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is not a folder inside the zip file as folders are not created by the command. I've edited my post to show an example of this.

Comment: Ahh thats the problem I had a confusion because a few days ago everything was fine but right now i see that in lastest build my customer packed everything in that subfolders so my question right now is pointless. Thanks for that